# Ĉu 'foruziĝonta" signifas same kiel "foruzota"?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

Ĉu 'foruziĝonta" signifas same kiel "foruzota"? Kaj ĉu ambaŭ ĝustas gramatike?

Comment: Ekzemple: Pro nia troa manĝado, la sandviĉoj estis foruziĝontaj. Pro nia troa manĝado, la sandviĉoj estis foruzotaj.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a lot of people, who are intrigued by the theoretical possibility in Esperanto, that you can take any root and add to it any pre- and/postfix, even multiple ones. Unfortunately given the sheer amount of possible combinations I would say, that most of these combinations do not make sense. Then there is a large grey zone of such combinations, that make sense in a very specific context. The smallest group is those combinations, that are in wide use. I'm inclined to think, that *foruziĝi* – and its partciples – fall into the senseless category.

- the prefix *for-* means away
- the root verb *uzi* means to use
- the combination [*foruzi*](http://vortaro.net/#foruzi) means *tute konsumi per uzado*, e.g. *dum la lasta vintro oni foruzis la tutan provizon da ligno* : during the last winter they used up all their stock of wood

In PIV there is one verb with *-uziĝi*, [*eluziĝi*](http://vortaro.net/#eluzi%C4%9Di) which means *difektiĝi pro longa uzado*, e.g. *tiu ĉi ŝtofo tre malrapide eluziĝos* : this cloth will become worn out slowly.

As Eduardo points out, *-iĝi* means, that the act takes place by itself. [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/igh.html) has a whole chapter about the postfix *-iĝi*. Since *foruzi* is a transitive verb, "you use up something", the act of using up can't happen by itself, i.e. no *foruziĝi*.

What seems to throw many English-speakers off when it comes to *-iĝi* verbs and participles, are two things:

- because of the extremely strict word order in English English uses more passive voice than is needed in Esperanto (and when needed prefer the oni-passive whenever possible because of its simplicity)
- many English-speakers try to map the *-ing* ending of English into a partciple in Esperanto while the *-ing* form can stand for different things, not all expressed by participles in Esperanto, see https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/3674

Coming back to your example in your comment there is a verb *formanĝi : tute konsumi per manĝado*, "to eat up".

- *La sandviĉojn oni formanĝis* : The sandwiches were eaten up.

Or if you need have a future aspect

- *La sandviĉojn oni lasis por formanĝi* : The sandwiches were left for to be eaten up.

Answer (score 1):

Se temas pri la foruzo de X:

`foruziĝonta`: la foruzo de X okazos per si mem.

`foruzota`: io foruzos X-n, kaj kutime tiun informon oni provizas.

Se vi aldonas ekzemplajn frazojn aŭ kuntekston oni povas pli detale respondi.

Comment: Ekzemple: Pro nia troa manĝado, la sandviĉoj estis foruziĝontaj.  Pro nia troa manĝado, la sandviĉoj estis foruzotaj.

Comment: @AJWentworth, ĉu vi povas aldoni ĉi tiun komenton rekte al via demando por havi pli da kunteksto?